# python dict comprehension working locally but not on server - version issue

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I quite perplexed by the following. I want to create a dictionary that maps id names to list items:

```
itemsKeyedById = {i["id"]: i for i in myList}
```

and it works normally when executed on my computer. myList is a list created by a series of commands like :

```
myList.append({'name': 'entry_name_string', 'id': 'some_id'})
```

When I upload it to a server, the script just "hangs" at this line.

The version of python I have locally is Python 2.7.10, and on the server I have 2.6.6. Maybe it's version issue, but I'm quite new to python and never programmed in 2.6.6. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you everybody :-)

Comment: To be clear, what you're doing in that first line is a `dict` comprehension, not a `list` comprehension. The name is based on the result type (in this case, a `dict`), not the input (because any comprehension can "comprehend" over any finite iterable input; the result is what is known, the input is arbitrary).

Comment: Thank you, this really makes it more clear to me. I have another issue, a similar line of code dosn't work in 2.7, could you help on this one too:

`topLevelItems = [item for item in myList if "parent" not in item]`

Comment: There's nothing about that line itself that should cause an error, but don't ask new questions in the comments of another; post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I think I found a workaround: 
`topLevelItems = []
for item in myList:
 if "parent" not in item:
  topLevelItems.append(item)`, I'm just not sure it's giving the same result all the time.

Comment: @PeterT it would be good to have two `virtualenv` environments. One with python2.6 and one with python2.7. `pip install virtualenv`

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов wow this question is from 3 years ago, yes indeed, `virtualenv` or containerization (i.e. with Docker) is good general solution to control your dev/staging/production environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2.6 does not have dict comprehension change it to

```
itemsKeyedById = dict((i["id"], i) for i in myList)
```

afaik it also does not have set comprehension nor set literals(unrelated to your question but another datastructure in 2.7 that is not in 2.6) ... you actually need to do `set([1,2,3])`

Comment: it doesnt suck it, just is an evolving language ... by the time python4 comes around people will say the same things about 3 ... that you have special cases for a couple datastructures does not really impact your productivity much, you still have most of the advantages that come from using python

Comment: That was really fast and exact! Thank you